# Cannot create any containers in Docker "Unable to find image 'all:latest' locally"

Tags: docker

After a recent update to Docker I find myself unable to create any new containers in Docker. I've already rebooted my operating system and Docker itself. I've tried specifying the tags to specific versions any way I could. I can manually pull the images I want with Docker. But it refuses to run or create any new containers. Already existing containers start up just fine. The full error message is below.

**Unable to find image 'all:latest' locally
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for all, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied**

These aren't from private repositories. These are all public projects from Docker Hub. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try explicitly specifying the repo when pulling the image. Also search the repo yourself to ensure it exists

Comment: I am using an existing config that worked before. I am updating a container's image by deleting the container and recreating it. I also searched on Docker Hub to ensure it exists. Something is wrong with my Docker where it's ignoring the tags I'm using.

Comment: Does the image exist? `docker images`. The image probably got deleted so you can no longer create a container from it.

Comment: Yes, the image exists. It exists locally and it exists in the repository. I also tried for other images too. It's doing this to any image I try.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. You're trying to build using an image called `all:latest` but if you look on the docker registry that doesn't exist.

https://hub.docker.com/_/all

Are you sure you're not trying to build from a private repository?

Comment: Correct. It's doing this to all of my new containers. I went to update a container today using an existing config. So I deleted it and went to recreate it and then I received that error message. As an example, I was trying to build plexinc/pms-docker. Something happened to my docker where it is ignoring the tags and looking for all:latest today no matter what I put.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I started taking my Docker command apart and found there was an environment variable that had the word "all" in it. Docker was completely ignoring whatever I had for the image and using the environment variable for the image. As soon as I removed this environment variable Docker started working again correctly.

The variable in question is -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: "all" \ to make sure the Plex container can see that there is an nVidia GPU available. I was using the wrong guide and found out it's supposed to be -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \ instead.